# Determining whether an Integral is positive, negative or zero?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, polar-coordinates

I have a question "*Sketch the region of integration and, without evaluating, determine whether the integral is positive, negative, or zero. Then evaluate each integral.*"

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2-x}\sin(x+y) \ dy\ dx$$

I can definitely evaluate this and it evaluates to $\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi/2-x}\sin(x+y) \ dy\ dx = 1$ which is a positive number.

The way this question is phrased makes it seems as though I have to determine if it is positive before I evaluate it. Can someone outline how I would do something like this?

Comment: The first part of your directions were to *sketch* the region of integration.  This ought to be done before assessing whether the result will be positive or not.

Answer (score 2):

The integral gives the signed area under the graph of a function. If the graph of the function is above the x-y plane (in other words, the function is positive over the region of integration) then the function will definitely have a positive integral.

All you need to do is sketch the parts of the plane where $\sin(x+y)$ is positive. If your region of integration falls inside one of those regions,then the integral will be positive.

Comment: I guess I must learn how to graph regions of integration to do this type of question

Comment: It is the triangle which intersects $(0,0), (0,\frac{\pi}{2}), (\frac{\pi}{2}$,0)

Comment: These are points on the xy plane? And if so, how did you come up with these numbers? I find it very hard to visualize this stuff. Do you have any sources where I can better learn to visualize problems like these by any chance?

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/integrating-multivariable-functions/double-integrals-topic/v/double-integral-1

This textbook is a great intro to multivariable calculus: http://www.synechism.org/wp/the-calculus-of-functions-of-several-variables/